# Getting incorrect score from fuzzy wuzzy partial_ratio

Tags: python, fuzzy-comparison, fuzzywuzzy

I am fairly new to Python and I am trying to use fuzzy wuzzy for fuzzy matching. I believe I am getting incorrect scores for matches using the partial_ratio function. Here is my exploratory code:

```
>>>from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
>>>fuzz.partial_ratio('Subject: Dalki Manganese Ore Mine of M/S Bharat Process and Mechanical Engineers Ltd., Villages Dalki, Soyabahal, Sading and Thakurani R.F., Tehsil Barbil, Distt, Keonjhar, Orissa environmental clearance','Barbil')
50
```

I believe this should return a score of 100, since the second string, 'Barbil', is contained in the first string. When I try taking off a few characters at the end or beginning of the first string, I get a matching score of 100.

```
>>>fuzz.partial_ratio('Subject: Dalki Manganese Ore Mine of M/S Bharat Process and Mechanical Engineers Ltd., Villages Dalki, Soyabahal, Sading and Thakurani R.F., Tehsil Barbil, Distt, Keonjhar, Orissa environmental clear','Barbil')
100
>>> fuzz.partial_ratio('ect: Dalki Manganese Ore Mine of M/S Bharat Process and Mechanical Engineers Ltd., Villages Dalki, Soyabahal, Sading and Thakurani R.F., Tehsil Barbil, Distt, Keonjhar, Orissa environmental clearance','Orissa')
100
```

It seems to switch from a score of 50 to a score of 100 when the length of the first string goes to 199. Does anyone have insight as to what might be happening?

Answer (score 2):

It's because when one of the strings is [200 characters or longer, an automatic junk heuristic gets turned on in python's SequenceMatcher](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/difflib.html#difflib.SequenceMatcher).
This code should work for you:

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

def partial_ratio(s1, s2):
    """Return the ratio of the most similar substring
    as a number between 0 and 100."""

    if len(s1) <= len(s2):
        shorter = s1
        longer = s2
    else:
        shorter = s2
        longer = s1

    m = SequenceMatcher(None, shorter, longer, autojunk=False)
    blocks = m.get_matching_blocks()

    # each block represents a sequence of matching characters in a string
    # of the form (idx_1, idx_2, len)
    # the best partial match will block align with at least one of those blocks
    #   e.g. shorter = "abcd", longer = XXXbcdeEEE
    #   block = (1,3,3)
    #   best score === ratio("abcd", "Xbcd")
    scores = []
    for (short_start, long_start, _) in blocks:
        new_long_start = max(0, long_start - short_start)
        new_long_end = new_long_start + len(shorter)
        long_substr = longer[new_long_start:new_long_end]

        m2 = SequenceMatcher(None, shorter, long_substr, autojunk=False)
        r = m2.ratio()
        if r > .995:
            return 100
        else:
            scores.append(r)

    return max(scores) * 100.0
```